# WPF ListBox - how to put values from dataTable?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, datatable

I have `ListBox` and want to put values in this listbox from a `DataTable`:

```
listBoxVisibleFields.DataContext = SelectedFields;
```

Where `SelectedFields` is a `DataTable` filled with data. But this code does not work. My `ListBox` is empty. As I remember, in WinForms was sucha a thing for list box like `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`, but in WPF I dont find something like that...

Does someone know how to fill simply my `ListBox` from `DataTable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you are looking for is `ItemsSource` instead of `DataContext`. The property most closely resembling ValueMember is called `SelectedValuePath` (see [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx)). The analogon for DisplayMember is called `DisplayMemberPath`.

---

EDIT: So, your code should look like this:

```
DataTable SelectedFields = ...;
listBoxVisibleFields.SelectedValuePath = "myID";
listBoxVisibleFields.DisplayMemberPath = "myTextField";
listBoxVisibleFields.ItemsSource = SelectedFields.DefaultView;
```

Alternatively, the two path values can be set in XAML

```
<ListBox ... SelectedValuePath="myID" DisplayMemberPath="myTextField" />
```

which is a bit more elegant.

Comment: Ok, i changed it to :
listBoxVisibleFields.ItemsSource = SelectedFields as IEnumerable;
But his does not work to, listbox is empty anyway.

Comment: Try `SelectedFields.DefaultView`.

Comment: Using `as` in such situations is dangerous, since it fails silently if the cast fails rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Maybe yuo also know how to set myId and myTextField for an comboBoxEdit in Devexpress WPF? I have posted earlier a question on that, but no one answered it...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with the Devexpress stuff, but binding a "normal" WPF ComboBox works just like a ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code, hope is usefull

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(local);Database=Catalogos;UID=sa;Password=S1santan"
Dim conSQL As New SqlClient.SqlConnection()
conSQL.ConnectionString = connectionString
conSQL.Open()
Debug.Print("SELECT * FROM CodigoPostal WHERE CP= '" & _Codigo & "'")
Dim adaptSQL As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CodigoPostal WHERE CP= '" & _Codigo & "'", conSQL)

Dim DatosCP As New DataSet
adaptSQL.Fill(DatosCP, "CodigoPostal")

'Here you select the table inside a data set
ListBox1.ItemsSource = DatosCP.Tables("CodigoPostal").DefaultView
'Here select which field to show
ListBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "d_asenta"
'and at last here you select the field you want to use to select values from
ListBox1.SelectedValuePath = "ID"

conSQL.Close()
```