# Fill ListBox with db query results

Tags: c#, wpf, database, listbox

As the title suggests, I'm trying to fill a `ListBox` with the results of a db query, though I'm not sure how to manage this. I've managed to populate a `DataGrid` from another query, but I'm not sure how to do the same with a `ListBox`. I'm sure it's simple, but I'm missing something! Similar overflow pages/google searches haven't yet yielded a clear answer. I'm using c# in a WPF app in visual studio.

In a separate class I have this:

```
public DataTable FillAllMenuItems()
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DustCatcher\Documents\pizzeria.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM MenuItems", con);
     SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable("Menu Items");
     sda.Fill(dt);
     return dt;
}
```

As an aside, I'm sure the above is messy so any pointers there would be great (do I need a `using` anywhere there?). On the relevant window cs file I have:

```
User user = User.GetInstance();
lstbxAllItems.ItemsSource = user.FillAllMenuItems().DefaultView;
```

Running the app, the `ListBox` has `System.Data.DataRowView` as many times as there are items in the database. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Set the `ValueMemberPath` and `DisplayMemberPath` of your `ListBox` also I would recommend to use `using` statements for your `SqlConnection, SqlCommand` etc. Link for the `ItemSource` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790878/wpf-listbox-how-to-put-values-from-datatable

Comment: Displaymemberpath did it - thanks for your comment!

Comment: @user2946329 thanks for the lesson in brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `lstbxAllItems.DisplayMemberPath` after `lstbxAllItems.ItemsSource`:

```
lstbxAllItems.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; // Or any column you want to show in your ListBox
```

But as a better approach you can use `ListView.ItemTemplate` and `Binding` for this purpose. Something like this:

```
<ListBox Name="lstbxAllItems">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, adding displaymemberpath did the trick! I'll read up a bit more about your suggested alternate method, as I'm not too sure how to implement it correctly!

Answer (score 1):

```
private void BindListbox() 
{
    myListBox.DataSource = dt;
    myListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I wanted to avoid further methods before I get bogged down in them all!

Comment: In WPF `DisplayMember` should be `DisplayMemberPath`. Please edit your answer and change it to `DisplayMemberPath`.